# Assign the return of a function to a variable with window.after

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on day 89 of 100 Days of Code: Python. I need to build a Tkinter app that constantly monitors a text entry and will delete the code if it detects that nothing's been typed for 10 seconds. I've tried to do so using this code:

```
def get_wordcount(self):
    start_num_char = len(self.entry_box.get(1.0, "end-1c"))
    new_num_char = self.after(5000, self.get_wordcount)
    if new_num_char <= start_num_char:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I have also tried:

```
    def get_wordcount(self):
    start_num_char = len(self.entry_box.get(1.0, "end-1c"))
    new_num_char = self.after(5000, len(self.entry_box.get(1.0, "end-1c")))
    if new_num_char <= start_num_char:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

The problem is that new_num_char equals "after#0", "after#1", "after#2", etc. instead of equaling the new character count. How can I grab the new word count every five seconds? If I do:

```
def get_wordcount(self):
start_num_char = len(self.entry_box.get(1.0, "end-1c"))
self.after(5000)
new_num_char = len(self.entry_box.get(1.0, "end-1c")
if new_num_char <= start_num_char:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

This just freezes the whole window and I can't type into the entry box until the five seconds are up. I'd really appreciate some help on this; I've been trying to figure it out for a few days now. Full code below:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Focus Writer")
        self.background_color = "#EAF6F6"
        self.config(padx=20, pady=20, bg=self.background_color)
        self.font = "Arial"
        self.start = False
        self.time_left = 10
        self.title_label = Label(text="Focus Writer",
                                 bg=self.background_color,
                                 font=(self.font, 26))
        self.title_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
        self.explain = Label(text="Welcome to the Focus Writer app. You need to continuously input content in order to "
                                  "keep the app from erasing your data. If the app detects that you haven't written "
                                  "anything for more than 10 seconds, it will wipe everything, and you will need to "
                                  "start over. \n\nPress the start button when you are ready to begin.\n",
                             bg=self.background_color,
                             font=(self.font, 18),
                             wraplength=850,
                             justify="left",)
        self.explain.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)
        self.start_img = PhotoImage(file="play-buttton.png")
        self.start_button = Button(image=self.start_img,
                                   height=50,
                                   command=self.check_writing)
        self.start_button.grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.time_left_label = Label(text=self.time_left,
                                     bg=self.background_color,
                                     font=(self.font, 36))
        self.time_left_label.grid(row=2, column=1)
        self.entry_box = ScrolledText(width=80,
                                      height=20,
                                      wrap=WORD,
                                      font=(self.font, 14))
        self.entry_box.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)

    def countdown(self):
        if self.time_left > 0:
            self.time_left -= 1
            self.time_left_label.configure(text=self.time_left)
            self.after(1000, self.countdown)
        else:
            if self.get_wordcount():
                self.entry_box.delete(1.0, "end-1c")
            else:
                self.time_left = 0
                return False

    def get_wordcount(self):
        start_num_char = len(self.entry_box.get(1.0, "end-1c"))
        new_num_char = self.after(5000, len(self.entry_box.get(1.0, "end-1c")))
        if new_num_char <= start_num_char:
             return True
        else:
             return False

    def check_writing(self):
        self.start = True
        self.start_button["state"] = DISABLED
        self.entry_box.focus()
        self.get_wordcount()


app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: `after` can't get value - you have to use global variable for this.

Comment: I don't understand why you use `after` in this way. It is for running function after some time. And it  doesn't wait for result from `after`. If you want to do something then you should do it inside function executed with `after`

Comment: GUIs work different then text programs - you will have to organize it in totally different way . it may need to split code into: function which only set start values, function which is executed after some time and compare new value with new value and set result in global variable or it execute other function which will use this value. So it would be `A->(after)B->C` instead of `A->(after)B->(back)A`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would split in two functions

First which set `self.start_num_char` and run `self.get_wordcount()` after some time

Second (self.get_wordcount) which get `new_num_char`, compare with `self.start_num_char` - but it doesn't use `return` - it directly resets timer - `self.time_left = 10` - when text in entry is longer (or shorter).  And finally it keep `new_num_char` in `self.start_num_char` and runs again after short time

```
    def start_wordcount(self):
        self.start_num_char = len(self.entry_box.get(1.0, "end-1c"))
        self.after(50, self.get_wordcount)
        
    def get_wordcount(self):
        new_num_char = len(self.entry_box.get(1.0, "end-1c"))
        
        if new_num_char != self.start_num_char:  # longer or shorter
            self.time_left = 10 
            self.time_left_label.configure(text=self.time_left)
            self.start_num_char = new_num_char
            
        self.after(50, self.get_wordcount)
```

And at the same time counter display new time and clean `entry` when `self.time_left` is `0`

```
    def countdown(self):
        if self.time_left > 0:
            self.time_left -= 1
            self.time_left_label.configure(text=self.time_left)
            self.after(1000, self.countdown)
        else:
            self.entry_box.delete(1.0, "end-1c")
            self.start_num_char = 0
```

This count 10 seconds only when you don't type.

But it has small problem - because `counter` and `get_wordcount` run separatelly so sometimes `counter` changes time to `9` when `get_wordcount` is reseting variable and it can display `9` but it shouldn't. Maybe it should use real time and it should keep time when last key was pressed and use this value to calculate counter.

---

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Focus Writer")
        self.background_color = "#EAF6F6"
        self.config(padx=20, pady=20, bg=self.background_color)
        self.font = "Arial"
        self.start = False
        self.time_left = 10
        
        self.title_label = Label(text="Focus Writer",
                                 bg=self.background_color,
                                 font=(self.font, 26))
        self.title_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
        
        self.explain = Label(text="Welcome to the Focus Writer app. You need to continuously input content in order to "
                                  "keep the app from erasing your data. If the app detects that you haven't written "
                                  "anything for more than 10 seconds, it will wipe everything, and you will need to "
                                  "start over. \n\nPress the start button when you are ready to begin.\n",
                             bg=self.background_color,
                             font=(self.font, 18),
                             wraplength=850,
                             justify="left",)
        self.explain.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)
        
        self.start_button = Button(text='Start',
                                   command=self.check_writing)
        self.start_button.grid(row=2, column=0)
        
        self.time_left_label = Label(text=self.time_left,
                                     bg=self.background_color,
                                     font=(self.font, 36))
        self.time_left_label.grid(row=2, column=1)
        
        self.entry_box = ScrolledText(width=80,
                                      height=20,
                                      wrap=WORD,
                                      font=(self.font, 14))
        self.entry_box.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)
    
    def countdown(self):
        if self.time_left > 0:
            self.time_left -= 1
            self.time_left_label.configure(text=self.time_left)
            self.after(1000, self.countdown)
        else:
            self.entry_box.delete(1.0, "end-1c")
            self.start_num_char = 0

    def start_wordcount(self):
        self.start_num_char = len(self.entry_box.get(1.0, "end-1c"))
        self.after(50, self.get_wordcount)
        
    def get_wordcount(self):
        new_num_char = len(self.entry_box.get(1.0, "end-1c"))
        
        if new_num_char != self.start_num_char:  # longer or shorter
            self.time_left = 10 
            self.time_left_label.configure(text=self.time_left)
            self.start_num_char = new_num_char
            
        self.after(50, self.get_wordcount)

    def check_writing(self):
        self.start = True
        self.start_button["state"] = DISABLED
        self.entry_box.focus()
        
        self.start_wordcount()
        self.countdown()


app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:**

You may try to use `self.entry_box.bind('<<Modified>>', function)` to execute `function(event)` when text was changed. But on my Linux it runs only on first change.

---

**EDIT:**

I added `time.time()` to check time betwin changes and now it better display counter.

```
    def countdown(self):
        if self.time_left > 0:
            current_time = time.time()
            if current_time >= self.change_time + 1:
                self.time_left -= 1
                self.time_left_label.configure(text=self.time_left)
            self.after(1000, self.countdown)
        else:
            self.entry_box.delete(1.0, "end-1c")
            self.start_num_char = 0

    def start_wordcount(self):
        self.num_char = len(self.entry_box.get(1.0, "end-1c"))
        self.change_time = time.time()
        self.after(50, self.get_wordcount)
        
    def get_wordcount(self):
        new_num_char = len(self.entry_box.get(1.0, "end-1c"))
        
        if new_num_char != self.num_char:  # longer or shorter
            self.time_left = 10 
            self.change_time = time.time()
            self.time_left_label.configure(text=self.time_left)
            self.num_char = new_num_char
            
        self.after(50, self.get_wordcount)
```

Comment: Thank you, adding self.start_num_char to the init was a huge help in figuring this out. I now have a working (if very 90s-looking) app.

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this another way. Create a function cancels any previous attempt to clear the function and then schedules this function to be called in 10 seconds. Then, create a binding that calls this button on every key release. The entire mechanism takes only a half dozen lines of code.

Here's an example:

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.after_id = None

        text = tk.Text(self)
        text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        text.bind("<Any-KeyRelease>", self.schedule_clear_text)

    def schedule_clear_text(self, event):
        if self.after_id is not None:
            self.after_cancel(self.after_id)
        self.after_id = self.after(10000, event.widget.delete, "1.0", "end")

root = App()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what the self.after_id is supposed to do. I tried googling it but didn't find any results. If it's not too much trouble, could you explain what this does?

Comment: @Accela101: it's just a variable. You need to pass an id to `after_cancel`, and this keeps track of the id of the most recent job that was scheduled.